# ssh session not active paramiko

Tags: python, session, ssh, paramiko

I have a piece of code where I am trying to connect to a Windows machine through ssh by using Python's paramiko library. The first time I connect, it is successful. But the second time, I get the error "SSH session not active". Is it because I am trying to use it in two different functions? The code looks like this:

```
class setup():#gets executed first
    @test.subsection
    def test_connection(self):
        #connecting first time
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect("8.29.9.131", username = "user", password = "pass")
        ssh.close()

class test1():#gets executed next
    @test.setup
    def setup(self): #runs first
        #connecting second time
        self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.ssh.connect("8.29.9.131", username = "user", password = "pass")

    @test.maintest
    def main_test(self): #runs after setup section above
        in, out, err = self.ssh.exec_command("cmd /c C:\\\Python27\\\Scripts\\\module.py")
        print out.readlines()
        self.ssh.close()
```

The traceback looks like this:

```
2015-01-20T15:42:23: %test-ERROR:     stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command("cmd /c C:\\\Python27\\\Scripts\\\module.py")
2015-01-20T15:42:23: %test-ERROR:   File "build/bdist.linux-     x86_64/egg/paramiko/client.py", line 341, in exec_command
2015-01-20T15:42:23: %test-ERROR:     chan = self._transport.open_session()
2015-01-20T15:42:23: %test-ERROR:   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/transport.py", line 615, in open_session
2015-01-20T15:42:23: %test-ERROR:     max_packet_size=max_packet_size)
2015-01-20T15:42:23: %test-ERROR:   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/transport.py", line 696, in open_channel
2015-01-20T15:42:23: %test-ERROR:     raise SSHException('SSH session not active')
```

Comment: I haven't used the testing framework you're using, though in the rather widespread Python "unittest" framework, I'd have expected similar code to work, with test1's self.ssh being available for further use by main_test.  You're also using a really old class system, since you don't have "class test1(object)" or the even more normal "class TestSshToPc(unittest.TestCase)" that I'd have expected.